# JavaScript load txt word list won't populate array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to remove a list of stopwords from a string. The list is loaded in line 3 below using $.get.
If I try to console.log(stop_words) inside $.get function I can retrieve the data. But they are not added to the array stop_words in a way, so that I can use the data outside of the $.get function.

Note: The code below works fine if I declare the values of the array directly inside the prototype.

**How do I assign data to stop_words array in such a manner, that I can use it outside of $.get function?**

```
String.prototype.removeStopWords = function() {
    var stop_words = [];
    $.get('rsc/stopord.txt', function(data) {
        stop_words = data.split('\n');
    });
    var x;
    var y;
    var word;
    var stop_word;
    var regex_str;
    var regex;

    var cleansed_string = this.valueOf();

    // Split out all the individual words in the phrase
    words = cleansed_string.match(/[^\s]+|\s+[^\s+]$/g)

    // Review all the words
    for(x=0; x < words.length; x++) {
        // For each word, check all the stop words
        for(y=0; y < stop_words.length; y++) {
            // Get the current word
            word = words[x].replace(/\s+|[^a-z]+/ig, "");   // Trim the word and remove non-alpha

            // Get the stop word
            stop_word = stop_words[y];

            // If the word matches the stop word, remove it from the keywords
            if(word.toLowerCase() == stop_word) {
                // Build the regex
                regex_str = "^\\s*"+stop_word+"\\s*$";      // Only word
                regex_str += "|^\\s*"+stop_word+"\\s+";     // First word
                regex_str += "|\\s+"+stop_word+"\\s*$";     // Last word
                regex_str += "|\\s+"+stop_word+"\\s+";      // Word somewhere in the middle
                regex = new RegExp(regex_str, "ig");

                // Remove the word from the keywords
                cleansed_string = cleansed_string.replace(regex, " ");
             } 
        }
    }
    return cleansed_string.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, "");
}

function keywordDensity() {
    var input = tinyMCE.activeEditor.getContent({format : "text"});
    input = input.replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/ig, "").replace(/,/g, "").replace(/-/g, "").replace(/"/g, "").replace(/'/g, "").replace(/\./g, " ");
    input = input.toLowerCase();
    input = input.removeStopWords();
    console.log(input);
    var keyword = $("#keyword").html();
    var wordCounts = { };
    var words = input.split(" ");
    words = words.filter(Boolean);

    for(var i = 0; i < words.length; i++)
        wordCounts["_" + words[i]] = (wordCounts["_" + words[i]] || 0) + 1;

    keysSorted = Object.keys(wordCounts).sort(function(a,b){return wordCounts[b]-wordCounts[a]})

    for(var i = 0; i < keysSorted.length; i++) {
        keysSorted[i] = keysSorted[i].replace(/[_-]/g, "");
    }

    var regexString = keysSorted[0];
    var regex = new RegExp("\\b" + regexString, 'g');
    var countMostUsed = input.match(regex, regexString);
    console.log(input.match(regex, regexString));
    console.log("You use the word " + keysSorted[0] + " " + countMostUsed.length + " times");
     }
```

Comment: You need a onsuccess event on your $get. asynchronous loading.

Comment: The `$.get()` is **asynchronous**. The callback you pass in will be invoked when the HTTP request completes, but the call to `$.get()` itself returns immediately. Basically, most of the work in your code should be done from inside that callback.

Comment: @Mistergreen is right, just to be more clear about it: everything in your code works fine, the problem is that your function is not waiting for your $.get call to finish before running the rest of your code, so your code keeps running and your stop_word is not populated yet. So add your code to a success callback function.

Comment: Thanks @Mistergreen 
I've been trying some different alert setup like those on https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/ but I can't seem to get a grasp on what a succes callback is.

It does the alerts and says 'suceed' and all. But no data is loaded

If anyone know of a great ressource on this a link or reference would be great :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Mistergreen, @Pointy and @phobia82 have already commented, you need to do the processing inside the callback. Or better yet, after the data has been received, using `then`.

```
String.prototype.removeStopWords = function() {

    var stop_words = [];
    var self = this;
    return $.get('stopword.txt', function(data) {
        stop_words = data.split('\r\n');
    }).then(function(){
      var x;
      var y;
      var word;
      var stop_word;
      var regex_str;
      var regex;

      var cleansed_string = self.valueOf(); // note: we can't use this here

      // Split out all the individual words in the phrase
      words = cleansed_string.match(/[^\s]+|\s+[^\s+]$/g)

      // Review all the words
      //for(x=0; x < words.length; x++) {
          // For each word, check all the stop words
          for(y=0; y < stop_words.length; y++) {
              // Get the current word
              //word = words[x].replace(/\s+|[^a-z]+/ig, "");   // Trim the word and remove non-alpha

              // Get the stop word
              stop_word = stop_words[y];

              // If the word matches the stop word, remove it from the keywords
              //if(word.toLowerCase() == stop_word) {
                  // Build the regex
                  regex_str = "^\\s*"+stop_word+"\\s*$";      // Only word
                  regex_str += "|^\\s*"+stop_word+"\\s+";     // First word
                  regex_str += "|\\s+"+stop_word+"\\s*$";     // Last word
                  regex_str += "|\\s+"+stop_word+"\\s+";      // Word somewhere in the middle
                  regex = new RegExp(regex_str, "ig");

                  // Remove the word from the keywords
                  cleansed_string = cleansed_string.replace(regex, " ");
              // } 
          }
      //}
      return cleansed_string.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, "");

    });
}
```

Note: I'm not sure why you need to iterate on individual `words` in the `String`. So I've commented out that part. You can find working code [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/dMQDG9yQFd93mWLb6w30?p=preview)

You will need to change the way you call the function as shown below.

```
"abc test1 test2 xyz".removeStopWords().then(function(data){
  alert(data); // alerts "abc xyz"
  // do rest of the processing that is dependent on the return value of `removeStopWords`
});
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch. I've never done anyting with .then before so it took a while for me to make this work. But now it is perfect :D

Answer (score 0):

This is not recommended, as your get request can block your script until it returns a result, but for the record, you can use this instead of the $.get():

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'rsc/stopord.txt',
    success: function(data) {
        stop_words = data.split('\n');
    },
    async: false
})
```

EDIT:

Your success callback is the function:

```
function(data) {
    stop_words = data.split('\n');
}
```

that you pass to the $.get() call. It's called when the $.get request has received a response, which can take some time... Your code after the $.get can run before the callback gets called, hence your problem...